# Why can't de Broglie waves be electromagnetic in nature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that the wavelength of de Broglie waves for a photon is same as that of the wavelength of the electromagnetic radiation that carries this photon. Doesn't this prove that matter waves  are em waves? Is there any other answer to this except that em waves require accelerated charge particles for their generation, and since photons move with constant speed of light, matters waves associated with photon can't possibly be em in nature?

Comment: *Doesn't this prove that matter waves are em waves?* - no, it only proves that photon waves are light waves. Why should this apply to anything other than photons?

Comment: Understood, so, can we say that at least in this particular case of photons, photon waves are em waves?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: so, em waves can be generated with constantly moving particles?

Comment: @Swami: Photons are quanta. That has a different meaning than "particle", although for many purposes one can treat them the same. Conceptually, however, it would be important for you to understand the difference, if you are curious about quantum mechanics .

Answer (score 2):

Some of my recent results may be highly relevant to your question. For example ( http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140%2Fepjc%2Fs10052-013-2371-4.pdf - published in the European Physical Journal C, open access; http://akhmeteli.org/akh-prepr-ws-ijqi2.pdf - published in the International Journal of Quantum Information), I showed that the matter field can be algebraically eliminated from the equations of scalar electrodynamics (the Klein-Gordon-Maxwell electrodynamics) in the unitary gauge. The resulting equations describe independent dynamics of the electromagnetic field. Similar results were obtained for spinor electrodynamics (the Dirac-Maxwell electrodynamics) - please see the article in the Eur. Phys. J. C. Therefore, modified Maxwell equations can describe both the electromagnetic field and the matter field.

However, that does not mean that "matter waves are em waves", not always: while it may be true, for example, for electrons and positrons, that does not mean it is also true for, say, neutrons, as strong forces cannot be described by electromagnetic waves, at least I don't know how this can be done. However, there is a possibility that matter waves are a more general gauge field, as it is not obvious that my results cannot be generalized, say, to the Standard Model.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I appreciate your effort akmeteli, but this went way over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Considering atoms or electrons under De Broglie effect, we may say that these are electrical dipole oscillating. They will cause electromagnetic emissions. These EM waves can cause interference too.